# How to have collections populated in a module for use inside events/commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I know that to have a collection populated such as guilds and channels, the bot must have logged in already, i.e. it can be used inside command files as well as inside events. What I have is a module that will display my logs inside my control discord server, and I want to be able to reference this module inside my events as well as my commands.

I have tried importing the module inside of the events, as well as other options that would make sense.

This is the code inside my module

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const CC = '../settings/control-center.json'
const CCFile = require(CC)
const GUILD = bot.guilds.get(CCFile.GUILD)
const STARTUP = bot.channels.get(CCFile.STARTUP)
const INFO = bot.channels.get(CCFile.INFO)
const ERRORS = bot.channels.get(CCFile.ERRORS)
const RESTART = bot.channels.get(CCFile.RESTART)
const EXECUTABLES = bot.channels.get(CCFile.EXECUTABLES)

class Control {
    /**
     * Implement control center logging
     * @param {string} message - What to send to the startup channel
     * @return {string} The final product being sent to the startup channel
     */
    STARTUP(message) {
        return STARTUP.send(`${message}`)
    }
}

module.exports = Control
```

I want to be able to globally use this module/the functions inside, so that my code can be more compact. So how can I have it so that this code is only loaded once the bot is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module code, you are creating a new Discord client instance, and never calling the login method.
A better approach would be to pass the bot object in your method

**module file**

```
const CC = '../settings/control-center.json';
const CCFile = require(CC);
const GUILD = CCFile.GUILD;
const STARTUP = CCFile.STARTUP;
const INFO = CCFile.INFO;
const ERRORS = CCFile.ERRORS;
const RESTART = CCFile.RESTART;
const EXECUTABLES = CCFile.EXECUTABLES;

class Control {

  startup(bot, message) {
    return bot.channels.get(STARTUP).send(message);
  }

}

module.exports = Control
```

**app file**

```
// Use the bot here
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client() 
const control = require('path/to/control.js');

[...]

// to send a message when ready, try something like this
bot.on('ready', () => {
  control.startup(bot, 'bot is ready');
});

// don't forget to login
bot.login('YOUR-TOKEN-HERE');
```

Comment: Works exactly as expected, great explanation, thank you.